# SQL counting total Subscriber Key from an Email Address with a special condition

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, automationstudio

I would like to output to the Data Extension below by using SQL Activity to _Subscribers Data Extension in Data View.

I tried using Count and Group By Email Address but the result only allow an email to appear once,

meanwhile I would like it to appear together with all different subscriber keys and with the same number of "Total Subscriber Key with the same Email address" they may have.

| Email Address | Subscriber Key | Total Subscriber Key with the same Email address |
| --- | --- | --- |
| email1@gmail.com | qwerty | 2 |
| email2@gmail.com | asdfgh | 1 |
| email1@gmail.com | zxcvbn | 2 |

Thank you for your time and I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

> I tried using Count and Group By Email Address but the result only
> allow an email to appear once

Then you're halfway there. What you need to do next is join the query you currently have as a subquery with the `_Subscribers` data view again like this:

```sql
Select top 987654321
    b.EmailAddress,
    a.SubscriberKey,
    b.SubscriberCount
From    
    _Subscribers a
Join
    (
        /* Your query here */
    ) b
On
    b.EmailAddress = a.EmailAddress
Order by 
    SubscriberCount desc
```

Just place your query in designated place and replace `SubscriberCount` with your name which should store the *Total Subscriber Key with the same Email address*.

Comment: Thank you Rafal, it worked like a champ!